# I have a jquery query

Tags: jquery-mobile, cordova

So I have been working on this phone gap application that uses jquery-mobile. Recently, my application stopped working in iOS but it would work on other platforms and even when opened in a browser.

It took me and my boss about a week to find out that the code causing the problem was this:

```
$.mobile.touchOverflowEnabled = true;
```

I recently updated my jquery-mobile version to 1.1. Any ideas why this piece of code does not work in iOS?

Comment: jQM 1.1 is not yet released, did you mean 1.0.1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not just remove touchOverflowEnabled? Do you have a fixed toolbar? I think all it does is allow a fixed toolbar to scroll with the app smoothly.

Check out what the doc's say about it: http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/toolbars/bars-fixed.html scroll down to "true fixed toolbars"

Comment: ya I removed it because I didn't really need it. But it would have been nice to have it working because it looks pretty cool.

Comment: The way a lot of apps solve the "fixed" toolbar problem is to do the toolbar natively and the rest of the app in phonegap.